# rails_admin, mongoid and problems with custom ActiveModel Validators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

I have a model that makes use a number of Custom ActiveModel Validators. While installing rails_admin, I get the following error

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bundler/gems/rails_admin-0d80b74a60e7/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid.rb:340:in `block in length_validation_lookup': undefined method `attributes' for #<MyCustomValidator:0x00000105c5aca0 @options={}> (NoMethodError)
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bundler/gems/rails_admin-0d80b74a60e7/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid.rb:339:in `select'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bundler/gems/rails_admin-0d80b74a60e7/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid.rb:339:in `length_validation_lookup'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bundler/gems/rails_admin-0d80b74a60e7/lib/rails_admin/adapters/mongoid.rb:98:in `block in properties'
```

The error goes away if I comment out the validator call in the model. Was wondering if there is a solution to the problem (other than hacking the rails_admin code base).

Below is the skeleton code (only the relevant parts)

```
class MyModel
   include Mongoid::Document
   ....
   validates_with MyValidator
end

class MyValidator <  ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
  end
end
```

As I mentioned in the comment, adding an 'attributes' method that returns an empty array resolves the issue.

Comment: Probably start with posting some code of yours?

Comment: I kind of got over the issue temporarily by adding an 'attributes' method that returns an empty array in my validators.

Answer (score 0):

That was my fault.
Now it's fixed in the latest master by:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/commit/1bc66862d41e048f5ae9b8ae0b639f2f58015a2a

Thanks for using RailsAdmin!